# Setting gym enviroment locally

Tags: r, openai-gym

I try to run the example for gym package

Here are the line until the problem:

```
library(gym)

remote_base <- "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
client <- create_GymClient(remote_base)

# Create environment
env_id <- "CartPole-v0"
instance_id <- env_create(client, env_id)
```

The error is this:

> ```
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>   Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
> ```

How is it possible to fix it?

I installed the gym package without any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to start the server in a separate terminal. Try

```
python gym_http_server.py
```

as described in the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/paulhendricks/gym-R#setting-up-the-server).